# How to keep track of element from another dataframe in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"call 1": ['debit card','bond',np.nan],
                  "call 2": ['credit card','mortgage','spending limit'],
                  "call 3":['payment limit',np.nan,np.nan]})
```

which is:

```
       call 1          call 2         call 3
0  debit card     credit card  payment limit
1        bond        mortgage            NaN
2         NaN  spending limit            NaN
```

I've further done some clustering and produce a new df as:

```
dfc = pd.DataFrame( {'cluster 1': ['payment limit', 'spending limit'],
 'cluster 2': ['debit card', 'credit card'],
 'cluster 3': [ 'bond', 'mortgage']})
```

as

```
        cluster 1    cluster 2 cluster 3
0   payment limit   debit card      bond
1  spending limit  credit card  mortgage
```

Now in `dfc` I want to know where each word is coming from for example `payment limit` is originally from `call 3` etc. In fact I wonder how to make a new df from these two dataframes such that I have:

```
print(pd.DataFrame( {'cluster 1': [{'call 3': 'payment limit'}, {'call 2':'spending limit'}],
 'cluster 2': [{'call 1':'debit card'}, {'call 2':'credit card'}],
 'cluster 3': [ {'call 1':'bond'}, {'call 2':'mortgage'}]}))
```

Comment: Would a basic brute force solution work for you?

Comment: It should be generalisable as the number of clusters as well as the number of columns and words would change

Comment: okay, providing a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dfc.applymap(lambda x: df[df.eq(x)].dropna(how='all').dropna(axis=1).to_dict('records')[0])
```

Output:

```
                      cluster 1                  cluster 2               cluster 3
0   {'call 3': 'payment limit'}   {'call 1': 'debit card'}      {'call 1': 'bond'}
1  {'call 2': 'spending limit'}  {'call 2': 'credit card'}  {'call 2': 'mortgage'}
```

Comment: Hey :) just added a extension to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73358723/keep-track-of-elements-of-a-dataframe it seems this method would fail to generalise, if elements aren't fully distinct.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a lookup dictionary and add the key:value from our first dataframe. For the second dataframe we replace the values if the same is found in our lookup dictionary

```
lookup_dict = {}
look_df = df.T

for col in look_df.columns:
    lookup_dict.update(dict(zip(look_df[col], look_df.index)))

pd.concat([dfc.replace(lookup_dict), dfc]).astype(str).groupby(level=0).agg(tuple)
```

##### Output :

This gives us :

```
                  cluster 1              cluster 2           cluster 3
0   (call 3, payment limit)   (call 1, debit card)      (call 1, bond)
1  (call 2, spending limit)  (call 2, credit card)  (call 2, mortgage)
```

To get the same as dictionary you can try

```
pd.concat([dfc.replace(lookup_dict), dfc]).astype(str).groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: dict([tuple(x)]))
```

##### Output :

```
              cluster 1                    cluster 2                 cluster 3
0   {'call 3': 'payment limit'}     {'call 1': 'debit card'}  {'call 1': 'bond'}
1   {'call 2': 'spending limit'}   {'call 2': 'credit card'}  {'call 2': 'mortgage'}
```

Note that we have used `aggregate` here instead of tuple.
Difference being, `apply` applies the function to each group. Your function returns 1, so you end up with 1 value for each of 3 groups.

`agg` aggregates each `column (feature)` for each `group`, so you end up with one value per column per group.

Comment: Hey :) just added a extension to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73358723/keep-track-of-elements-of-a-dataframe it seems this method would fail to generalise, if elements aren't fully distinct.